# Nav Graph scoped ViewModel functions not resolving

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm attempting to get a ViewModel scoped to a navigation graph and am not able to get `NavController.getViewModelStoreOwner(id)` or the delegate `by navGraphViewModels(id)` to resolve. I must be missing a dependency but haven't been able to find the correct one.

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.2.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.cren90.sandbox

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.findNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        navController.getViewModelStoreOwner(R.id.nav_graph) // getViewModelStoreOwner is not resolving
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your navigation dependencies are using `android.arch.navigation`, meaning you are only getting the `1.0.0` version of the pre-AndroidX Navigation.

They need to be `androidx.navigation` if you want to use the AndroidX versions.

```
// This includes navigation-fragment and navigation-runtime-ktx already
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.0'
// This includes navigation-ui already
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.0'
```

Comment: Knew it was going to be something dumb... Thank you for pointing that out!